# webpack-dev-server proxy: context with wildcard

Tags: webpack, http-proxy, webpack-dev-server

I want to proxy /v1/* to http://myserver.com, and here is my script

```js
devServer: {
  historyApiFallBack: true,
  // progress: true,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  // https: true,
  port: 8081,
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  proxy: {
    '/v1/*': {
      target: 'http://api.in.uprintf.com',
      secure: false
      // changeOrigin: true
    },
  },
},
```

but it doesn't work,
[image]

Comment: Where do you need to put the configuration?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Update:*
thanks to @chimurai, setting `changeOrigin: true` is important to make it work.

[Underneath](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib%2FServer.js#L143) `webpack-dev-server` passes all the proxy configuration to `http-proxy-middleware`, from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching). It's clear the use case you want is actually achieved with `/v1/**` path:

```
devServer: {
   historyApiFallBack: true,
   // progress: true,
   hot: true,
   inline: true,
   // https: true,
   port: 8081,
   contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
   proxy: {
     '/v1/**': {
       target: 'http://api.in.uprintf.com',
       secure: false,
       changeOrigin: true
     }
   }
 },
```

Comment: Should work with the proxy option: `changeOrigin: true`

Comment: `changeOrigin: true/false, Default: false - changes the origin of the host header to the target URL` Yeah, it did work. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm new to webpack, where do you put the configuration for a proxy?

Comment: which version of webpack support this proxy feature, I am using webpack: 3.11.1 and webpack-dev-server: 2.9.6 and http-proxy-middelware: 0.19.1.
This proxy configuration is not working for me, I have tried every possible combinaton of the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that your request url and port matches that which your webpack-dev-server is running on. So, if your api is located at `http://localhost:5000`, and your dev server is running on `http://localhost:8080`, make sure all of your requests are to `http://localhost:8080`. Its best to make your requests to `localhost:8080/api` (to avoid conflict with app routes) and use the path rewrite to remove the /api.

**Example:**

Webpack devserver proxy config:

```
proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
    },
}
```

Webpack dev server running on:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Desired API endpoint:

```
http://localhost:5000/items
```

In your app, make the request to:

`http://localhost:8080/api/items`.

This *should* work. It seems to me that all of the above issues stem from making the request to the API url and port rather than the webpack dev server url and port and using the proxy and path rewrite to direct the request to the API.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me.

```
    devServer: {
        host: '11.11.111.111',          //local ip
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: outputpath,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true,
        proxy: {
          '/api':{
                target:'http://example.com',
                pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''},
                secure:false,
                changeOrigin:true
          }
        }
    },
```

//use

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'/api/pvp/share/getsharecfg.php',
        dataType:'json',
        ...
```

Comment: Please add more informations to your answer. A good answer is more as a code block.