# Proxy requests to a separate backend server with vue-cli

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I am using `vue-cli` `webpack-simple` template to generate my projects, and I'd like to proxy requests to a separate, backend server. How can this be easily achieved?

Comment: I didn't really take a close look at `vue-cli`'s boilerplate and used [this generator for yeoman](https://github.com/fountainjs/generator-fountain-vue) instead. It got me started even I had little knowledge of webpack/gulp/browser-sync(though there was a few gotchas when I tried to integrate it with backend). I think it's worth a look and choosing between `vue-cli` and it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you use `webpack` template with `vue-cli`, then you can find the required information in this reference document:

http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html

Or instead of changing your template now, you may copy the relevant config from the `webpack` template into your local `webpack-simple` template.

**EDIT: more info from my local setup**

This is what I have in my `config/index.js` under `module.exports`:

```js
dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 4200,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            changeOrigin: true
        },
        '/images': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            changeOrigin: true
        },
        // and so on...
```

The above config runs my `vue-cli` on port 4200, and I run my server on port 8080.

**EDIT: Corrected info about CORS after comment #4 and #5**

**Note:**

- The `changeOrigin` option in `dev.proxyTable` (in webpack config) ensures that you do not need to serve CORS headers on your server API responses.
- If you decide to omit `changeOrigin` for any reason, then you need to ensure that your server API includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (or equivalent) in its response headers.

**References:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662307/654825
2. https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

Comment: So it's more difficult to using the webpack-simple template?

Comment: I think `webpack-simple` is intended to get started with Vue.js. The `webpack` template provides lot more configuration, and even has a [detailed help-page](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) for additional info.

Comment: As you rightly said, it becomes more difficult later if you start with the simple template and write a lot of code, as you need to do all the additional config work yourself.

Comment: We may not need CORS here, I added static file plugin/library to my backend so it can serve `index.html` and made the frontend develop server proxy every single request to backend server. No more CORS, a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just did some quick experiment locally and found that either we need CORS headers, or set `changeOrigin: true` in the proxyTable options for webpack dev. Server proxy is done using [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) - this github page confirms that `changeOrigin` option changes host headers to server URL (target).

Comment: @潘俊杰 I corrected my answer above, based on your comments. The server is a lot cleaner without CORS as you rightly said, and also avoids a potential security loophole, just in case the production server ends up serving those CORS headers.

Answer (score 65):

In **@vue/cli 3.x**:

- Create a `vue.config.js` file in the **root** folder of your project, if you don't already have one.
- Have its contents as follows:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/gists": {
        target: "https://api.github.com",
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now any call to (assuming your dev server is at `localhost:8080`) `http://localhost:8080/gists` will be redirected to `https://api.github.com/gists`.

## Another example: proxying all calls

Say you have a local backend server that is typically deployed at `localhost:5000` and you want to redirect all calls to `/api/anything` to it. Use:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "/api/*": {
                target: "http://localhost:5000",
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Annoying how it's not super easy to find this info with numerous google searches

Comment: Can anyone link to the docs where I *should* have found this information?

Comment: Relevant `devServer` Webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Answer (score 6):

```
module.exports = {

    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://genius.net',
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/api': ''
                }
            },
            '/auth': {
                target: 'http://genius23.net',
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/auth': ''
                }
            },
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it gives the pathRewrite. Unless you are adding /api to the URI of all of your dev servers you will need this.

Answer (score 0):

if these answers do not work

try to add 
http://127.0.0.1:{your port}
in my case it would not start without it