# Proxying webpack dev server in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I am trying to proxy all `api/` requests to `http://localhost:3000` using `vue-axios` and `vuex`. The output on the command line says that the proxy has been created but then it doesn't actually proxy to the right address and 404's.

I have the following setup inside of webpack:

```
dev: {
  env: require('./dev.env'),
  port: 8080,
  autoOpenBrowser: true,
  assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  assetsPublicPath: '/',
  proxyTable: {
    'api/': {
      target: 'https://localhost:3000/api',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api':""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And inside of my actions file I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export const register = ({ commit }, user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Vue.axios.post('users', user)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          debugger
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err)
          debugger
        })
  })
}
```

The console output suggests that the proxy has been established:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  https://localhost:3000/api
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
```

But when I actually call the function, it returns `http://localhost:8080/users 404 (Not Found)`

What is incorrect about this?

I have consulted

- Stackoverflow: [Proxy requests to a separate backend server with vue-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315451/proxy-requests-to-a-separate-backend-server-with-vue-cli)
- Vue docs: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html
- Github issues: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/458

None of those solutions worked.

I have heard this might be a problem with hmr but that doesn't seem likely.

Any ideas?

I have tried the following combinations:

```
  '/api': {
    target: 'https://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  },

  'api/': {
    target: 'https://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  },

  'api/*': {
    target: 'https://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  },

  '*/api/**': {
    target: 'https://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  },

  '*': {
    target: 'https://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  },

  '/api/*': {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    changeOrigin: true
  }

proxy: {
  "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "protocol": 'http:',
      "port": 3000
    },
    ignorePath: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false
  }
},
```

Comment: same problem here, still no solution

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same problem and tried everything.  It turns out the proxy appends the matched path segment `/api` onto the end of the target and looks there for the proxied file.  So this rule:

```
'/api/*': {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    changeOrigin: true
}
```

is actually seeking for the file here:

```
http://localhost:3000/api
```

Non-intuitive.  If you want this to function more intuitively and target the actual target, you need to remove the matched portion from the path like this:

```
pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
```

The correct rule becomes:

```
'/api/*': {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
}
```

For unknown reason, `pathRewrite` is not explicitly listed in the docs sidebar [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/), though it is tucked away in 1 location in the config guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a request to the following `Vue.axios.post("api/users", user)` instead.